# Is it possible to extend a continuous linear function from a basis to an entire Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach spaces over $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $B \subset X$ be a subset of $X$ such that it's linearly independent and $X=\overline{\operatorname{span}(B)}$.

Let $f : B \to Y$ be a continuous function.

Is it possible to extend $f$ to $F : X \to Y$ such that $F$ is a continuous linear function and $\forall b \in B : f(b)=F(b)$?

Comment: From the fact that $X=\overline{span(B)}$ you should get that you can extend the function in an unique way, what is left is that this new function is continuous linear.

Comment: Do you mean bounded on $B$ or continuous on $B$? These two notions don't necessarily coincide here, as $B$ is not a subspace. By the way, if you meant bounded on $B$, then it is not always possible to extend it. Can't say for sure about the other case though.

Comment: What does it mean for $f$ to be linear, when its domain is $B$?

Comment: @FrankMurphy it's not true what you say because $f$ is defined only in $B$

Comment: @treedetective I mean continuous  not in sense bounded

Comment: @Desire I mean $\forall b,c \in B$ and $\forall q,p \in \mathbb{C} : f(qb+qc)=qf(b)+pf(c)$

Comment: $qb+pc$ does not belong in $B$ (as $B$ is linearly independent). Just omit the word *linear* from the assumptions concerning $f$ and the question is legit. You can rephrase your question as: "If $f$ is a continuous function on $B,$ then is its (unique) linear extension on $\text{span} B$ also continuous?"

Comment: @treedetective i understood , you are right, so $f$ is not linear. can you help me to solve my question?

Comment: @MateyMath That's why I said the new function $F$, the one defined in $X$, the one that extends $f$.

Comment: I'll give it some more thought, but it doesn't look easy. If you could construct a Hamel basis $B$ with countably many isolated points (isolated in $B$), then the answer would be negative. I don't know, however, if you can find such a $B$. It looks a little counterintuitive for such a $B$ to exist, but at first glance it doesn't seem to contradict anything either.

Comment: @treedetective exuse me, this information may be useful, $B$ is compact and connected

Comment: The answer to the original question is negative: According to Theorem 3.8 of https://people.math.ethz.ch/~halorenz/publications/pdf/metal.pdf there exist Hilbert spaces with discrete (wow!) and closed Hamel bases $B$. Now just pick a countable subset of $B$, say $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and define $f(b_n)=n\|b_n\|$ for this sequence and $f(b)=0$ for the rest. Then $f$ is continuous on the discrete $B$, but its linear extension is unbounded. However, $B$ is never compact in Banach spaces, so this example is not a counterexample for $B$ compact+connected. Your new question is still unanswered...

Comment: thanks so much @treedetective very gentle, you are clarifying many interesting concepts. so, in general, if $B$ is closed the answer is no, or am i wrong?

Comment: You are welcome! If $B$ is discrete, or if it contains a countable discrete subset, it is definitely a 'no'. The $f$ that I defined in the previous comment is continuous because $B$ is discrete. (Actually every function defined on a discrete space is continuous and it is very easy to check it). $B$ being closed wasn't used in the previous argument. If $B$ is not discrete, it is not so easy to make sure that the $f$ you are trying to define is continuous.

Comment: ok @treedetective i understood there's no definitive answer because it depends on $B$ and $f$ so in general the answer is "no"... is it right?

Comment: Indeed. But for the special case where $B$ is compact and connected you might get a different answer.

Comment: i thanks you so much again @treedetective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not necessarily. Here's an example (with $B$ compact and connected):

Let $K$ be a metric space with diameter at most 1.

Let $B = \{\delta_x \ :\ x \in K\} \subset \mathrm{Prob}(K)$ be the set of point masses, and let $X_0$ be the vector space of complex-valued measures on $K$ with finite total variation. We can give $X_0$ the bounded Lipschitz norm $$\|\mu\| = \sup \left\{ \big\lvert \int f\, d\mu \big\rvert \ : \ f \in \mathrm{Lip}^1(K) , \ \|f\|_\infty \leq 1 \right\}$$ where $\mathrm{Lip}^1(K)$ is the set of 1-Lipschitz functions $K \to \mathbb{C}$. This norm restricts to the Wasserstein/transportation metric $\bar{d}$ on $\mathrm{Prob}(K)$, so $B$ is compact and connected if $K$ is (the map $x \mapsto \delta_x$ is an isometry $K \to B$). $B$ is also linearly independent.

The span of $B$ is dense in $X_0$: any $\mu \in X_0$ can be written as a linear combination of four probability measures on $K$ (first decompose into real and imaginary parts, then decompose these into their positive and negative parts). Each of these probability measures can then be approximated in transportation distance to arbitrary precision by measures with finite support.

$X_0$ is actually *not* complete. 
But the span of $B$ is still dense in the completion $X$ of $X_0$, and $B$ is still compact and connected when considered as a subset of $X$, so we can work in $X$ instead. The important thing is that we have a (complete, if you want) normed space containing $\mathrm{Prob}(K)$ such that the norm gives the transportation metric on $\mathrm{Prob}(K)$.

Let $\tilde{f} \colon K \to \mathbb{C}$ be an arbitrary continuous function, and let $f \colon B \to \mathbb{C}$ be the continuous function given by $f(\delta_x) = \tilde{f}(x)$. 
Suppose there were a linear, continuous extension $F \colon X \to \mathbb{C}$. Since $F$ is a continuous functional on a normed space it must be bounded, say $|F(\mu)| \leq C \|\mu\|$. But this means that
$$|\tilde{f}(x) - \tilde{f}(y)| = |F(\delta_x - \delta_y)| \leq C \|\delta_x - \delta_y\| = C d(x,y),$$
i.e. $\tilde{f}$ is Lipschitz. So as long as $K$ admits non-Lipschitz functions, not every continuous function on $B$ admits a continuous linear extension to $X$.

Comment: thanks csh for your answer

Answer (score 0):

For me continuous function on the basis $B$ means continuous on $Span(B)$ since $f$ is assumed to be inear, it has to be defined on a vector space.

Let $x\in X$, there exists $(x_n), x_n\in B, lim_nx_n=x$. Since the restriction of $f$ on $B$ is continuous, $\|f(x_n)-f(x_m)\|\leq \|f\|\|x_n-x_m\|$. This implies that $f(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Since $Y$ is complete, there exists $f(x)=im_nf(x_n)$.
Let $y_n$ be another sequence such that $lim_ny_n=x$. $lim_n(x_n-y_n)=0$. Since $f$ is continuous, $lim_nf(x_n-y_n)=lim_nf(x_n)-lim_nf(y_n)=0$. Implies that $f$ is well-defined on $X$.

$lim_n\|f(x_n)\|\leq lim_n\|f\|\|x_n\|=\|f\|\|x\|$ implies that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: The first line is wrong. For every $x\in X$ there exist $\lambda_{n,m}\in\mathbb{C},\ x_{n,m}\in B$ such that $\sum_m x_{n,m}\lambda_{n,m}\to x$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: @NombreFalso123 you are right, can you say if my question is possible?